# phpUnderControl centralized for projects on different servers?

Tags: php, continuous-integration, phpundercontrol, centralized

I didnt work with phpundercontrol yet and from what I read so far, I dont see whether you can use it to control/CI multiple projects that are "living" on different servers.

Do I really have to run phpundercontrol on each of the production servers? Cant I run a centralized phpundercontrol "to rule them all" ?

Helpful answers appreciated

EOF

Comment: I think that run CI on production server is not a very good idea. You must create a centralized server and fetch the code by your VCS system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can run a centralized phpundercontrol "to rule them all". Like already pointed out in the comments, you should have a dedicated server that simply fetches your various projects from your Version Control System and integrates/builds them. Unless these builds succeed, you should not deploy any of those projects to your production site.

On a sidenote, most people I know dont use PHPUnderControl anymore, but have moved to use http://jenkins-php.org, which is much easier to setup and configure.

Comment: so if I get you right, the projects are needed to be checked out to the server where phpundercontrol runs, are built and integrated there? That wouldnt work well in my case as the projects are complex in such matter that they need to be tested on a specific environment

Comment: @pHiL since we are talking PHP, what specific environment could that be and why cant you make that environment available on the CI server? Nothing stops you from using multiple PHP versions on the server.

Comment: well I can run much tests on a different server with the correct php environment but the applications have dependencies during runtime that "could" be difficult to test on a different server without the possibility to "talk" to the dependecies. will try it all out tho. thank you for your help :)

Comment: @phil all of your dependencies ought to be replaced with test doubles, e.g. mocks and stubs that allow for testing in complete isolation.